# How to convert a var which contains Long to an Long[]

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following:

```
var resourceids = racks.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value);
var resource = repository.GetResources(resourceids);
```

But i am not sure how i can convert the `var resourceids` to `long[]` as my repository method accept `long[]`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `a.Technology.IT360ID.Value` is a `long` then `resourceids` is actually an `IEnumerable<long>`.  So you just need to convert it using `ToArray()`:

```
var resourceids = racks.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value).ToArray();
var resource = repository.GetResources(resourceids);
```

Remember that `var` is not a "type" - it just lets the *compiler* determine the type versus declaring it explicitly.

This may be a case where it's better to explicitly declare the type versus using `var`:

```
long[] resourceids = racks.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value).ToArray();
var resource = repository.GetResources(resourceids);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Select` will return `IEnumerable<long>`. So, to convert to `long[]`, you can call [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) which forces immediate query evaluation and returns an array that contains the query results:

```
var resourceids = racks.Select(a => a.Technology.IT360ID.Value)
                       .ToArray();

var resource = repository.GetResources(resourceids);
```